# Flutter Sqflite - how to add conditions to present specific data into a listview

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am not sure how to go about it
I understood that I can use
"select * from" OR .where() function but I do not know how to implement it.

I have a third column in my database table that I intend to use to filter what is presented
any answers revolving this is greatly appreciated

any help is appreciate it cheers

*EDITED AGAIN*

this is my completed database helper. i sometimes come across the issue that the data type wont work when i make it equal to each other.

```
import 'package:progressiverecording/components/measurements/measurement_model.dart';
import 'package:progressiverecording/pages/recording%20measurements/measurement_main.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';








class MeasurementsDBHelper {

  static const _dbName = "measurement.db";
  static const _dbVersion = 1;

  static const tableName = "measurement_table";

  static const String columnId = 'id';
  static const String columnContent = 'content';
  static const String columnBodyPart = 'bodyPart';

  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    database.execute('''
         CREATE TABLE measurement_table (
         "$columnId" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        "$columnContent" TEXT NOT NULL,
        "$columnBodyPart" TEXT NOT NULL
         )
        ''');
  }

  static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    return sql.openDatabase(
      'measurement.db',
      version: _dbVersion,
      onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
        print("------- creating a table -------");
        await createTables(database);
      },
    );
  }

  static Future<int> insertMeasurement(String content, String bodyPart ) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();

    final data = {
      'content' : content,
      'bodyPart' : bodyPart,
    };

    final id = await db.insert(
        'measurement_table',
        data,
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace
    );
    return id;
  }

            //getting all items
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getMeasurements() async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    return db.query(
        'measurement_table',
        orderBy: "id",
    );
  }





            //getting individual item
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getMeasurement(int id) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    return db.query(
      'measurement_table',
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
      limit: 1,
    );
}

static Future<int> updateMeasurement( int id, String content, String bodyPart) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();

    final data = {
      'content' : content,
      'bodyPart' : bodyPart,
    };

    final result = await db.update(
      'measurement_table',
      data,
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    return result;
}

static Future<void> deleteMeasurement(int id) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    try {
      await db.delete(
        "measurement_table",
        where:  "id = ?",
        whereArgs: [id],
      );
    } catch (err) {
      debugPrint("Something went wrong when deleting an item: $err");
    }
}

  static Future<List<UserInputModel>> fetchDesiredData() async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    final result =await  db.rawQuery(
      '''
        SELECT * FROM measurement_table
        WHERE "bodyPart" = $fromBodyPart;
        ''',
    );
    return result.map((map) => UserInputModel.fromMap(map)).toList();
  } 



}
```

this is my listview with fieldbox. when i tell it to print the new value of the filtered data i get zero. but the current code prints all the data in the database.

the fetchFilteredData command is the equivalent function.

```
class MeasurementsDBHelper {

  static const _dbName = "measurement.db";
  static const _dbVersion = 1;

  static const tableName = "measurement_table";

  static const String columnId = 'id';
  static const String columnContent = 'content';
  static const String columnBodyPart = 'bodyPart';

  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    database.execute('''
         CREATE TABLE measurement_table (
         "$columnId" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        "$columnContent" TEXT NOT NULL,
        "$columnBodyPart" TEXT NOT NULL
         )
        ''');
  }

  static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    return sql.openDatabase(
      'measurement.db',
      version: _dbVersion,
      onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
        print("------- creating a table -------");
        await createTables(database);
      },
    );
  }

  static Future<int> insertMeasurement(String content, String bodyPart ) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();

    final data = {
      'content' : content,
      'bodyPart' : bodyPart,
    };

    final id = await db.insert(
        'measurement_table',
        data,
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace
    );
    return id;
  }

            //getting all items
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getMeasurements() async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    return db.query(
        'measurement_table',
        orderBy: "id",
    );
  }





            //getting individual item
static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getMeasurement(int id) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    return db.query(
      'measurement_table',
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
      limit: 1,
    );
}

static Future<int> updateMeasurement( int id, String content, String bodyPart) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();

    final data = {
      'content' : content,
      'bodyPart' : bodyPart,
    };

    final result = await db.update(
      'measurement_table',
      data,
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    return result;
}

static Future<void> deleteMeasurement(int id) async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    try {
      await db.delete(
        "measurement_table",
        where:  "id = ?",
        whereArgs: [id],
      );
    } catch (err) {
      debugPrint("Something went wrong when deleting an item: $err");
    }
}

  static Future<List<UserInputModel>> fetchDesiredData() async {
    final db = await MeasurementsDBHelper.db();
    final result =await  db.rawQuery(
      '''
        SELECT * FROM measurement_table
        WHERE "bodyPart" = $fromBodyPart;
        ''',
    );
    return result.map((map) => UserInputModel.fromMap(map)).toList();
  }



}
```

this is my model class.

```
class UserInputModel {
  int? id;
  String? content;

  UserInputModel({
    this.id,
    required this.content,
});

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  var map = <String,dynamic> {};
  map['id'] = id;
  map['content'] = content;
  return map;
}

factory UserInputModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => UserInputModel(
  id: map['id'],
  content: map['content']
);

}
```

simply put, my current code right now allows me to print all the user input into the listviews. i have multiple pages showing the same structure but i want each page to represent data that was pass strictly through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: console]

Create Model Class:

```
class Fields{
  static const String id = '_id';
  static const String content = 'content';
  static const String bodyPart = 'bodyPart';

  static const  List<String> values = [id,content,bodyPart];
}

class UserModel{
  int? id;
  String content;
  String bodyPart;

  UserModel({
    this.id,
    required this.content,
    required this.bodyPart,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      Fields.id: id,
      Fields.content: content,
      Fields.bodyPart: bodyPart,
    };
  }

  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserModel(
      id: map['_id'] as int,
      content: map['content'] as String,
      bodyPart: map['bodyPart'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Database Helper:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflowhelp/model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const String databaseName = "measurement.db";
const String tableName = "measurementTable";

class MeasurementDatabase{
  static final MeasurementDatabase instance = MeasurementDatabase._();

  MeasurementDatabase._();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await _initDB(databaseName);
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreateDB);
  }

  Future _onCreateDB(Database db, int version)async{
    const idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
    const textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';

    await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE $tableName(
    ${Fields.id} $idType,
    ${Fields.content} $textType,
    ${Fields.bodyPart} $textType
    )
    ''');

    debugPrint("success!!! DB Created");
  }

  ///Create Measurement
  Future createMeasurement(UserModel user)async{
    final db = await instance.database;

    debugPrint("Added Content : ${user.content} with ${user.bodyPart} to DB");

    return await db.insert(tableName, user.toMap(),conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);

  }

  Future<List<UserModel>> fetchMeasurement(String bodyPart)async{
    final db = await instance.database;

    final result = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE ${Fields.bodyPart} = ?",[bodyPart]);

    return result.map((e) => UserModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }

  Future<List<UserModel>> fetchAllMeasurement()async{
    final db = await instance.database;

    final result = await db.query(tableName);

    final List<UserModel> allMeasurements = result.map((e) => UserModel.fromMap(e)).toList();

    return allMeasurements;
  }

}
```

HomePage:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflowhelp/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflowhelp/model.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<UserModel> fetchedData = [];

  final bodyParts = ["Head","Arms","Chest","Torso","Legs","Back","Neck","Head","Arms","Chest","Torso","Legs","Back","Neck"];

  void createDummyData()async{
    for(int i = 0; i< bodyParts.length; i++){
      await MeasurementDatabase.instance.createMeasurement(UserModel(content: "${Random().nextInt(10)}", bodyPart: bodyParts[i]));
    }
  }

  void fetchBodyPart(String bodyPart)async{
    fetchedData = await MeasurementDatabase.instance.fetchMeasurement(bodyPart);

    debugPrint("Fetching: $bodyPart");
    for(UserModel user in fetchedData){
      debugPrint("Content: ${user.content} with Body Part: ${user.bodyPart}");
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => createDummyData(),
            child: const Text("Create Dummy Data"),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => fetchBodyPart("Torso"),
            child: const Text("Fetch Body Part"),
          ),

          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: fetchedData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(fetchedData[index].content),
                subtitle: Text(fetchedData[index].bodyPart),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have added some code for reference, thanks again for the help

Comment: hello man, thanks again for your time and assistance. i wasnt able to correctly implement your model. when i tell it to print the number of values in the newly filtered list i get zero. what i understand is that the function in the databasehelper is either not reading the complete list to filer or is not even filtering. im also getting the error: "no such colum exists". Thanks again for your help really appreciate it

Comment: my bad, I made a small mistake in the raw query. I've updated my answer with my own tested code. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much man, i wish i can tell you the time i spent on this. i really appreciate it mate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you said i right, You can do with two ways adding condition directly in your sql query and fetching the according data:

```
  static Future<dynamic> _fetchDesiredData(
  {required String where,
  required String whereTerm,
  required String tableName}) async {
  /* Creating the raw query for fetching desired data. */

    dynamic desiredData = await _db.rawQuery(
      '''SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $where==$whereTerm;''');

    return desiredData;
  }
```

here you need to pass the column name in `where` whose data you want to filter and the filter term in `whereTerm` and it will get your filtered data, You can play with it add more conditions if you want more advance filtration.

Or you and fetch all the data and filter your list.

```
List<CarDm> filteredList = carsDmList.where((ele) => ele.brand=='bmw');
```

here you can add more condition will putting `||`(or)  `&&`(and) conditions.

Comment: i tried to do so, i have updated my question, cheers

Comment: you have posted the same code snippet of `MeasurementsDBHelper` class, add the implementation of your UI part ListView and other stuff.